# Unable to get routing work in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

I am unable to get routing to work for the Ionic app. 
When I click on a link ('Scientific Facts') in home.html, it doesn't navigate to facts.html
I've gone through all the relevant documentation and other similar answers on stack overflow but none of them helped.

Below are my files index.html, app.js, states.js files. Could someone please suggest where I could be going wrong ?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/states.js"></script>


    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="curie">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Facts">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

states.js

```
angular.module('curie')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.facts', {
    url: '/facts',
    views: {
      'facts': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/facts.html'
      }
    }
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');


})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
     $scope.goToUrl = function(path) {
        $location.path('#/tab/overviewPhoto');
    };
});
```

app.js

```
angular.module('curie', [
  'ionic', 
  'ngCordova', 
  'ui.router',
  ])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From further research, I've come to know that, the view name the page is being navigated to, shall be same as the view name from which it was navigated from.

Below is **incorrectly** defined view name.

```
  .state('tab.facts', {
    url: '/facts',
    views: {
      'facts': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/facts.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

Below is **correctly** defined view name i.e same as the view name it is being navigated from.

```
  .state('tab.facts', {
    url: '/facts',
    views: {
      'home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/facts.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Adding on to this, I'm not sure why you're using views. You'd use views if you had multiple views on a state. Otherwise you can just simplify your state definition to

.state('tab.facts', {url:'/facts', templateUrl:'templates/facts.html'})

Comment: also, you can try using ui-sref="tab.facts" instead of href

Answer (score 0):

since, you are using `$stateProvider`, why don't you use `$state.go('urPage')`.
 **In your view:**

```
<a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="goFacts()">Scientific Facts</a>
```

**In your controller:**

```
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
     $scope.goToUrl = function(path) {
        $location.path('#/tab/overviewPhoto');
    };//u don't have this function in the view.

    $scope.goFacts = function(){
       $state.go('tab.facts');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Crhistian Ramirez said try to use ui-sref instead of href.

**Old solution:**

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

**New solution:**

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>
        <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tab.facts">Scientific Facts</a>
      </p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```